# PIC18F97J60 Increment FSR not affecting INDF

Tags: assembly, microcontroller, pic18

```
    ; point FSR0 to address 0x0 and set INDF to 'A'
    movlw   0x0
    movwf   FSR0
    movlw   A'A'
    movwf   INDF0

    ; increment FSR0, then set new INDF to 'B'
    incf    FSR0
    movlw   A'B'
    movwf   INDF0

    ; decrement FSR0, then show the new INDF to LCD, it should show the letter 'A', but 'B' is shown.
    decf    FSR0
    movf    INDF0, 0
    call    LCD8SendData
```

Why 'B' is shown instead of 'A'? I have decrement the FSR0 pointer.

Comment: Do you have a simulator to single step through your code?

Comment: Maybe your `LCD8SendData` function has a bug. Use a debugger to verify the results of each instruction.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem, I didnt set the address for FSR0 as I thought the system will set it. After I set the addr of FSR0 to 0x9EF, it starts to work now, thanks everyone for helping :)